# Multiple inner Knapsack and Fitness Calculation

Tags: c#, genetic-algorithm, knapsack-problem, genetic-programming

Scratching my head on this one and I might be thinking it wrong.

Basically it's the Knapsack Problem but modified. You have a set of items with various weights on them and you are to put it in three knapsacks with a capacity of 20 each.

I have codes to initialise all the items randomly in the sacks. That means I can have a sack with more than 20, less than 20, and equal to 20. The problem is that the items are all being added hence my total score is the same for all population making it impossible to mutate.

for example,

- KnapsackA 1 score = 72
- KnapsackA 2 score = 50
- KnapsackA 3 score = 10

If I have a population of four, that means I'll have other objects of the genome with knapsacks like these of different scores between knapsacks but the total will be the same.

- KnapsackB 1 score = 80
- KnapsackB 2 score = 18
- KnapsackB 3 score = 34

I just had a thought that I could be running a code to randomly generate a random number to re-assign the items for the first generation rather than in initialise, but I could be wrong as well. .

How do I go about calculating a unique score (evaluating the fitness) that way I can remove the lowest genomes and mutate on the remaining ones?

Score - capacity is always the same number.

(x post in other forum)

Comment: Sorry but your explanation isn't particularly clear. How about a quick preface describing the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Edited my question to hopefully make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a different coding of the information, in order to allow an item to be out of the knapsacks.

For example, I would consider a gene as a knapsack number for an item, and `0` to indicate the item isn't in any knapsack:

```
gene[0] = 1 (item 0 is in knapsack 1)
gene[1] = 0 (item 1 is not in any knapsack) 
gene[2] = 3 (item 2 is in knapsack 3)
gene[3] = 2 (item 3 is in knapsack 2)
gene[4] = 1 (item 4 is in knapsack 1)
```

So an individual represents a possible solution for the 3 knapsacks. And you can have for example 100 individuals in the population.

With this coding of the information, computing mutations and reproduction is easy.

To mutate a gene, you just have to assign it a new value that is a random number in the range [0,3]. For example, the mutation algorithm:

```
n = number of genes
mutation_rate = 0.01 // it means a mutation rate of 1%
For i from 0 to n-1
  r = random real number between 0.0 and 1.0
  If(r < mutation_rate) 
    gene[i] of new individual = (random integer number) modulo 4
  Else
    gene[i] of new individual = gene[i] of original individual
  EndIf
EndFor
```

If you want to implement reproduction, you just have to select the half of the genes of the first individual, and the opposite half of the genes of the second individual.

```
n = number of genes
For i from 0 to n-1
  r = random integer number
  If(r modulo 2 == 0) 
    gene[i] of new individual = gene[i] of first individual
  Else
    gene[i] of new individual = gene[i] of second individual
  EndIf
EndFor
```

You can combine the two precedent algorithms in one, in order to compute the mutated children of two individuals more efficiently than to first compute a child, and then mutate it.

I'm not an expert in fitness functions, but I think you can inspirate you from the following one, that is very basic and just take in consideration the fact that the knapsacks must be filled as much as possible. For this fitness function, the higher the value of fitness is, better is the solution:

```
n = number of genes

fitness = 0

weight_noknapsack = 0
weight_knapsack1 = 0
weight_knapsack2 = 0
weight_knapsack3 = 0

For i from 0 to n-1
  Switch gene[i]

    case 0: weight_noknapsack += item[i].weight

    case 1: weight_knapsack1 += item[i].weight

    case 2: weight_knapsack2 += item[i].weight

    case 3: weight_knapsack3 += item[i].weight

  EndSwitch
EndFor

If(weight_knapsack1 <= MAX_WEIGHT_KNAPSACK1)
  fitness += weight_knapsack1
EndIf
If(weight_knapsack2 <= MAX_WEIGHT_KNAPSACK2)
  fitness += weight_knapsack2
EndIf
If(weight_knapsack3 <= MAX_WEIGHT_KNAPSACK3)
  fitness += weight_knapsack3
EndIf
```

It computes a fitness, but I think there may be better fitness functions.